# My bottom border is not viewable @ screen width <700 px. How do I add some space between the bottom of the page and my bottom border?

Tags: html, css, border

[image: Top border can be viewed]

[image: Bottom border is missing cause is stuck to the bottom of the webpage]

As can be seen from the 2 images above @ screen width below 700 px, my top border can be clearly seen while my bottom border is stuck to the bottom of the page and can't be view. Any idea how to fix this? I want to have some space between the bottom of the webpage to my bottom border.

Even after adjusting the margin of the main element or outer most div container, I still can't get some extra space to render between the bottom margin and bottom-end of the webpage.

Appended below is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/gsy1m0w7/

CSS:

```
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 70vw;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
}

section {
    /* background-color: greenyellow; */
    height: 400px;
    width: 350px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

div {
    /* background-color: red; */

    /* border-color: 3px solid black; */
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;  
    padding: 0 20px;
}

img#img1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

section.panel {
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

a {
    text-transform: uppercase;  
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#main_container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

button {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    padding: 8px 13px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

a.price {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: skyblue;
}

hr {
    width: 50%;
}

span {
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    section {
        /* background-color: greenyellow; */
        /* height: 400px;
        width: 350px; */
        display: flex;
        width: 70vw;   
    }

    section.panel {
        border-right: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    }

    div {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    button {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    #main_container {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        height: 0px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main_container">
    <main>
        <section class="panel" id="panel1">
            <img id="img1" src="rocket.gif" alt=""><a href="">Personal</a> 
            <hr>
            <div><a href="">Custom Domain</a></div>
            <hr>
            <div><a href="">Sleeps After 30 Mins Of Inactivity</a></div>
            <hr>
            <div><a class="price" href="">Free</a></div>
            <div>
                <button>SIGN UP</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="panel" id="panel2">
            <img id="img1" src="target.gif" alt=""><a href="">Small Team</a> 
            <hr>
            <div><a href="">Never Sleeps</a></div>
            <hr>
            <div><a href="">Multiple Workers For More Powerful Apps</a></div>
            <hr>
            <div><a class="price" href="">$150</a></div>
            <div>
                <button>FREE TRIAL</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="panel3">
            <img id="img1" src="presentation.gif" alt=""><a href="">Enterprise</a> 
            <hr>
            <div><a href="">Dedicated</a></div>
            <hr>
            <div><a href="">Simple Horizontal Scalability</a></div>
            <hr>
            <div><a class="price" href="">$400</a></div>
            <div>
                <button id="lastbutton">FREE TRIAL</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer or not but see what happens if you add `padding-bottom` to `main-container` and also, just to see what it looks lke try the same thing on  your `<footer>`. Fairly sure that the height of your content will still be taller than the screen though.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://imgur.com/a/8tIeKPQ

Comment: The id `main_container` should not have `height: 0`. That make everything overflow and ignore margin, padding bottom.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob I tried adding padding bottom, but it doesn't work

Comment: @vee my main container is actually at height of 100vh.

Comment: From your screenshot the screen width must be small or narrow. Resize it to the same as in your screenshot and inspect it. It is `0px` not `100vh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set #main_container to height: 100%;

Comment: Tried. Still can't.

Comment: in your mediaquery. where you have it set as 0

Comment: look under the @media in styles. You have set height of #main-container to 0 for view width up to 700px. Which is why your 100vh is being overridden

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/elissi/hy8d4t56/3/

Comment: This answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Apply padding to the top and bottom of `<main>`. Doing this will make the `main` always fluid in relation to any content that is in it.

50px top and bottom padding only.

```
main{
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```